# Which approach is best practice?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Which One of the Bean definition is best practice and why?

For an example Type 1 can be for Unit testing without creating a context.

**Type 1**

```
public class MovieRecommender {

    private final CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;

    @Autowired
    public MovieRecommender(CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
        this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
    }

    // ...

}
```

**Type 2**

```
public class MovieRecommender {

    @Autowired
    public CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;


    // ...

}
```

Comment: Can you improve the title of the question? If I just read it, what can I think about it?

Answer (score 4):

I would say the first one. Not only due to the fact that you can easily test it but because of one simple rule

> At the end of its constructor an object should have everythig it needs to actually perform its task

(I'm sorry, I don't remember where I read it :( Anyway, I think it's quite a good rule to follow)

So, by implementing your classes like the second way you can create instances that **doesn't** have what they need. You have to **instantiate** it and **set** its dependencies. What happens if you forgot the last part?

So that's why I always recomend constructor injection AND setting the dependencies as `final` so it doesn't compile unless you set them in the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Hands down **Constructor dependency injection** should be preferred over **field dependency injection** for the reason you have mentioned: You can't test it as a regular POJO.

Expanding the discussion over **Constructor vs Setter method dependency injection** as per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-setter-injection):

> [..] it is a good rule of thumb to use constructors for mandatory
>   dependencies and setter methods or configuration methods for optional
>   dependencies

Answer (score 1):

I would say first one is better.

Main reason why I would use it, is it's a lot easier and cleaner to set up test. You just create mocked dependencies and pass it to constuctor of your component under test.

As of Spring 4.3, classes with a single constructor can omit the `@Autowired`
annotation.

So you could write just:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

    private final CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;

    public MovieRecommender(CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
        this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
    }

    // ...

}
```

There is also one trick. If you will use it with `@AllArgsConstructor` from Lombok, then you also don't have to write constuctor (same as with field injection) and you also have convienient constructor for tests.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MovieRecommender {

    private final CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao; //injected

}
```

So if you're using Lombok, I would go with constructor injection + `AllArgsConstructor`.

There are some also some great articles about this [issue](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/software-development/design/why-i-changed-my-mind-about-field-injection/).

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest **Type 2**

Because anyway you are using annotations to inject dependency to class  which is done by using **Reflection API**
..

So there is no use of initialization through constructor...

If you don't want to use annotations then use as per requirement means --

If you are going to change(initialize) value after object creation through setter methods then go for setter injection ..

Setter injection override the value of properties which is initialized with constructor injection if both injection available..

Answer (score 1):

The first one (also known as contructor dependency injection) primarily because its easier to test.  If you wanted to mock customerPreferenceDao you can mock it and inject it into an instance of MovieRecommender.  It gives you more control of what you're doing.