# How to mock the Keycloak framework methods using Mockito in java

Tags: java, mockito, keycloak, junit5

I'm the having functionality to fetch the following details from KeyCloak.

1. User details
2. Realm details
3. Client details

I want to write the test cases for those functionalities using Mockito.

below is code logic for fetching those details.

```
@Autowired
private Keycloak keycloak;
@Value("${keycloak.realm}")
private String realm;


public Optional<UserModel> getUsers(String userId) {
  UserResource userResource = keycloak.realm(realm).users().get(userId);
  if (userResource == null)
    return Optional.empty();
  UserRepresentation userRepresentation = userResource.toRepresentation();
  UserModel userModel = new UserModel(userRepresentation.getId(), userRepresentation.getFirstName(),
      userRepresentation.getLastName(),
      userRepresentation.getUsername(),
      userRepresentation.getEmail(), userRepresentation.isEnabled(),
      new Date(userRepresentation.getCreatedTimestamp()),
      new Date(userRepresentation.getCreatedTimestamp()),
      userRepresentation.getGroups(),
      userRepresentation.getRealmRoles());
  return Optional.of(userModel);
}


public Optional<RealmModel> getRealm(String realmId) {
  RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realms().realm(realmId);
  if(realmResource == null)
    return Optional.empty();
  RealmRepresentation realmRepresentation = realmResource.toRepresentation();
  RealmModel realmModel = new RealmModel(realmRepresentation.getId(), realmRepresentation.getDisplayName());
  return Optional.of(realmModel);
}


public Optional<ClientModel> getClient(String clientId) {
  ClientResource clientResource = keycloak.realm(realm).clients().get(clientId);
  if(clientResource == null)
    return Optional.empty();
  ClientRepresentation clientRepresentation = clientResource.toRepresentation();
  ClientModel clientModel = new ClientModel(clientRepresentation.getClientId(), clientRepresentation.getName()) ;
  return Optional.of(clientModel);
}
```

I want to mock the KeyCloak methods in my test cases

for example

```
1. UserResource userResource = keycloak.realm(realm).users().get(userId);
2. UserRepresentation userRepresentation = userResource.toRepresentation();
```

I want to mock somethig like below

```
Mockito.when(keycloak.realm(Mockito.anyString()).users().get(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(userResource);
```

I don't know is there any option available, Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need to have a constructor to receive autowired objects and values instead of adding these annotations on the fields (which is also a [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46300324/which-approach-is-best-practice)):

```
// constructor
public YourBean(@Autowired Keycloak keycloak, @Value("${keycloak.realm}") String realm) {
    this.keycloak = keycloak;
    this.realm = realm;
}
```

After that, you will need to pass a mocked Keycloak object on the bean inside the test function:

```
Keycloak keycloak = Mockito.mock(Keycloak.class);
String realm = "mockedRealm";
YourBean bean = new YourBean(keycloak, realm);
```

So you can execute the `Mockito.when` functions. But pay attention that you will need to mock each function call in `keycloak.realms().realm(realmId)`. Using `Mockito.when` chaining functions won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, How to mock each function call in keycloak.realms().realm(realmId) here?